# Selenium crashes when window.onunload popup appears

Tags: selenium, popup, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a web application where I want to write a selenium test to assert that the modal popup (the one with "Stay on this page" vs. "Leave this page") is shown when the window gets closed and there are unsaved form changes.

In my selenium test i use `Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.CurrentWindowHandle).Close()` after I have made some unsaved form changes. The modal popup appears, so far so good. The idea was to excpect an `UnhandledAlertException` to make the test pass. But what actually happens is that selenium crashes.

Any ideas how to deal with that? I'm using the `C#` Version of Selenium with the `IE Driver` and `IE11`